# Is there really an embargo on Cuba?

Tags: united-states, sanctions, cuba

I have read about a few economists last weeks who defended that "The embargo doesn't really exist de facto.", "Cuba can negotiate with any country." or "The embargo is not applied".

Is that true? Is there really no embargo (or does it not apply somehow)?

I know that there is no **block** but an embargo. But what I do not know is if the embargo by the US really exists or if it is only a signed paper that is not actually applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is applied.

It is impossible for Cuba to trade with the USA. The USA makes it difficult for other countries to trade with Cuba - not impossible but difficult.

As an example, a communication from the Cuban government on the difficulties in coffee trade https://www.ico.org/documents/cy2020-21/ed-2355e-communication-cuba.pdf

That may be dramatised for effect, and represents a partisan case. Nevertheless even accounting for that, it is clear that the US does enforce its sanctions.